# Show that $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}f_n$ is uniformly convergent in $(-\pi,\pi)$ for $f_n := \ln(\cos(\frac{x}{n}))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem is stated as:

> Show that $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}f_n$ is uniformly convergent in $(-\pi,\pi)$ for $f_n := \ln(\cos(\frac{x}{n}))$

Here's my attempt at solving it:

Let's define $g(x) = \ln(\cos{\frac{x}{n}})$, whose derivative is given by $g'(x) = -\frac{\tan(x/n)}{n}$, which is clearly positive for $x \in (-\pi,0)$ and negative for $x\in(0,\pi)$, where $n\geq 3$. For $x=0$ we have our maximum.

Evaluating $g(x)$ for $x = 0$ gives us that $g(0) = 0$, hence, $\sup_{x\in(-\pi,\pi)} f_n(x) = 0 \forall n \geq 3$

Using Weierstrass M - test, we have that since $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} 0 $ is convergent, then the original functional series converges uniformly. Which was to be proven.

I hope I've presented my solution in a correct way. Please feel free to share any ideas on things that went wrong in my solution if there were any.

Thanks.

Comment: All this proves is that the sum doesn't diverge to positive infinity. You at least need a lower bound, and then from there you need some way of showing that the function is smooth.

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{{\left| {\log (\cos x)} \right|}}{{x^2 }} \le \frac{{\left| {\log (\cos (\pi /3))} \right|}}{{(\pi /3)^2 }} < 1
$$ for $|x|<\pi/3$, $x\neq 0$.

Comment: You just proved it using the power series of the cosine, the power series of the logarithm and the geometric series.

Comment: @MarcusLuebke Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Gary I'm sorry but I don't think I understand how that hint might help me further. I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing. I'd be glad if you could clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use
$$\log(x) \le x-1$$
for $x>0$. So you get
$$|\log(\cos(x/n))| \le 1- \cos(x/n).$$
Now use $\cos(x)=1+O(x^2)$ to get
$$|\log(\cos(x/n))| \le O(x^2/n^2).$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty |\log(\cos(x/n))| < \infty$$
for $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$. Since $|\log(\cos(x/n))|$ is maximal for $x=\pi$ this implies also uniform convergence.